# List all possible combinations of pandas dataframe values to reach a certain sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
party seats
A      34
B      26
C      19
D      12
E      10
```

There are always 101 seats in total. I need to get a list of all possible combinations of parties, which have 51 or more seats together.

For instance,

```
[A, B]
[A, C]
[A, B, C]
[A, B, D]
...
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

or something like this. Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look into the "Knapsack Problem"

Comment: If the number of rows is not too big, you can brute-force it. For `n` rows there are `2^n` subsets which you need to calculate the sum.

Comment: Check out the recipe for _powerset_ in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) docs. It uses [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned "all combinations", I think you are not looking at one optimal solution. The only possibility would be to brute-force and generate all combinations of parties and choose the ones that have a sum greater than 51.

Here is one way of doing it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Data Generation
alphabets = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
party_size = 6
seats = 51
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20,100,party_size), index=alphabets[:party_size])

#Algo
parties = df.index
a = []
for r in range(parties.shape[0]): # Generate combinations
    ls = list(itertools.combinations(parties, r))
    ls1 = [inx for inx in ls if df.loc[inx,:].sum()[0] > seats] # Choose only what qualifies
    a.extend(ls1) # Generate master list
```